# How Can Access Label In Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

im try to access label in repeater to get value and set another value in same label

```
  <ul class="mail-list">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="repMsg" runat="server" DataSourceID="EDSrepMSg">

                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMsgDisplay" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Display_Msg" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("message_id") %>'>
                                                        <span class="mail-sender">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("message_from") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                                                        <span class="mail-subject">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("message_title") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                                                        <span class="mail-message-preview">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text='<%#If (Eval("message_description").ToString.Length > 10,Eval("message_description").ToString.Substring(0,10).TrimEnd() & "..",Eval("message_description"))%>'></asp:Label></span>

                                                    </asp:LinkButton>

                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDSrepMSg" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=BWJO_dbEntities" DefaultContainerName="BWJO_dbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="tbl_message"
                                            Where="it.message_to=@message_to and it.message_type=2 or it.message_type=4 " OrderBy="it.message_date desc">
                                            <WhereParameters>
                                                <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="user_id" Name="message_to" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />

                                            </WhereParameters>

                                        </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

### The output:

[image]

### Note:

> Theres no relationship btween tbl_msg,tbl_user,tbl_emp

i want just to know how to get value from

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("message_from") %>'></asp:Label>
```

then set value into lblEmail(Edit Label)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can first get label and then its value, something like this..
for example you have Label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblval" runat="server" Text="this is test"></asp:Label>
```

then at backend you can get text like:

```
protected void rptrMaylike_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label lblv = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblval");
        lblv.Text = "Value from code behind";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Usman Mirza for Give Me hint , i Solved it Like This:

***Create new label in repeater to read message_id**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMsgID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("message_id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span>
```

### Code behind:

```
Protected Sub repMsg_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repMsg.ItemDataBound

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim MsgID As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblMsgID"), Label).Text)


            Using context As New BWJO_dbModel.BWJO_dbEntities
                Dim obj = context.tbl_message.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.message_id = MsgID)
                Dim fromID = obj.message_from
                Dim ToID = obj.message_to
                Dim msgtype = obj.message_type
                If msgtype = 2 Then
                    Dim userObj = context.tbl_user.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.user_id = fromID)
                    Dim userEmail = userObj.user_email
                    Dim lblEmail = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblEmail"), Label)
                    lblEmail.Text = userEmail

                ElseIf msgtype = 4 Then
                    Dim empObj = context.tbl_employee.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.emp_id = fromID)
                    Dim empEmail = empObj.emp_email

                    Dim lblEmail = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblEmail"), Label)
                    lblEmail.Text = empEmail

                End If

            End Using



        End If
```

### Note:

message_type :

```
           1)user-user

           2)user-role

           3)role-user

           4)role-role
```